# JavaScript Functionality broken on web, but works in files

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dns

I made a site with this little page

nikhilgupta.paperplane.io/courseList.html

that should be clickable, and change colors, and have popovers etc, and it does when I open the files through my documents. However, when I hosted it on a domain, the functionality stopped working.

When I remove the https:// automatically inserted through chrome, most of the functionality returns. I think its because the domain is not verified, but I'm just guessing, and if it is the case, how do I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Try to load jQuery from your host, not from `googleapis`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are viewing a page with a secure connection (https), most browsers will block content on the page which is not secure. In your source you have

> `src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'`

which in this case is unsecure content.

You can reference like so:

> `src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'`

to choose http or https automagically based on the connection used.